# is fabricjs.d.ts really missing animate function?

Tags: typescript, fabricjs

I'm new to both fabric and typescript. Now that I'm trying to use the library, I came across a weird error. In my code I tried to do this:

```
    var rect = new fabric.Rect();
    rect.animate('angle', '-=5', {
        onChange: this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas)
    });
```

But it's telling me that `'Property animate does not exist on type IObject'`. When I checked the definition file, I saw that there's only a function called animate in fabric.util.

```
    var util: {
    addClass(element: HTMLElement, className: string);
    addListener(element, eventName: string, handler);
    animate(options: {
        onChange?: (value: number) => void;
        onComplete?: () => void;
        startValue?: number;
        endValue?: number;
        byValue?: number;
        easing?: (currentTime, startValue, byValue, duration) => number;
        duration?: number;
    });
    createClass(parent, properties);
    ... }
```

I got the definition from 
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fabricjs/fabricjs.d.ts

Is it really incomplete or am I missing something important?

Comment: It is not uncommon for definition files to have missing edge functions. It is however more common for library authors to miss documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I had a look and I think you're right.

It looks like all fabric objects should get the animate method, but in the typescript definition file, the IObject doesn't have the animate method specified and therefore no object would get the method including IRect which is/extends IObject.

I tried this and it works:

In fabricjs.d.ts find the IObject declaration (searching for 'interface IObject'), then add the line below.

```
export interface IObject extends IObservable {

    //this line:
   animate(property: string, value: any, options?: any): IObject;
```

Save the .d.ts file and it should work for your example, though the parameters may not be the ideal types.

Hope it helps.

Comment: PS. The DefinitelyTyped collection on GitHub are only put together by contributors, and looking through only 1 person (https://github.com/jschaf) has helped with the fabricjs so far, and only in December last year.  The more people that move to TypeScript and are fabric js users, hopefully the more contirbutors there will be to make the typescript def have full coverage.

Comment: Thank you John. I added your suggestion and it works perfectly. I'm adding some more things to the definition whenever I come across missing things. I'll probably soon add my changes to the repo too.